# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table - operating on model inheriting from not managed model

Tags: django, django-models, django-staticfiles

I'm having an issue building database schema for an app which includes model with image and which is being preloaded with some default data. The idea is that when application starts it's being prepopulated with default data (static images) but after that users can upload their own images.

To simplify let's say that model has only two fields - `shared_one` and `image`:

```
class Some(models.Model):
    shared_one = models.CharField()
    image = [???]
```

I tried to define `image` as `FileField` but it doesn't work with static files - while creating new record `Some` model will try to save new file `image` in `MEDIA_ROOT` directory.

Then I found out that Django introduces field type for managing static files in models - [FilePathField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#filepathfield) but obviously it doesn't comply with files uploaded by users.

Then I came up with an idea to make `Some` as an abstract class like that:

```
class Some(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    shared_one = models.CharField()


class DefaultSome(Some):
    media = models.FilePathField()


class UsersSome(Some):
    media = models.FileField()
```

The issue with that approach is that `DefaultSome` and `UsersSome` are now completely different beings - I cannot for example access `media` from other model using `ForeignKey` to `Some`, I'd need to create different sets of models (and database tables) for each new model that will be using `media` which seems super inefficient.

I tried also creating `Some` as a not managed model but it didn't work at all. Having models defined like that:

```
class Some(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
    shared_one = models.CharField()


class DefaultSome(Some):
    media = models.FilePathField()


class UsersSome(Some):
    media = models.FileField()
```

I tried to run script which generates default data. Script looks like that:

```
# it's defined in migration file and is meant to run with migrations

def populate_default_data(apps, schema_editor):
    DefualtSome = apps.get_model('myamazingapp', 'DefaultSome')
    DefaultSome.objects.create(
        shared_one="SomeSomeSome",
        media=os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, "media_file.jpg")
    )
```

But it fails with error: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: myamazingapp_some`. (???)

Is my data structure badly designed? Should I use completely different approach?

Answer (score 0):

Probably fake migration has been performed. Open your database open table `your_project.django_migrations`, then search for the migration file name that created the model. **Delete that migration record from table and again perform the migration.**